# How to drop frames while recording using Android media recorder

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am trying to record a slow-motion video. I'm using Android Camera2 API. I'm able to record the video at 120 FPS using Android media recorder library. I was looking for a mechanism to drop frames while recording via media recorder to get a variable fps video say 80 or 100 etc. It is important to note that 120 fps is a fixed fps range provided by camera 2 which cant be altered.

I have tried setting capture rate and frame rate method of media recorder in different variations but nothing seems to work.

```java
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(60);
mMediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(60);
```

what I had expected was to get a 60fps recorded video. but somehow video is still 120fps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is possible to deal with individual frames while working with MediaRecorder. I am trying something similar, particularly getting the camera-provided time stamps for my videos. You might want to look into [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) samples, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java) and how it records frames.

Also, if working with the camera2 API, you can consult the [StreamConfigurationMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap) for a camera on which stream configurations are possible.